# I want to use custom post query with one post offset

Tags: wordpress, post

I want to set custom post query without first post. for this issue I've used code listing bellow-

```
global $post;
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 3, 'offset' => 1,  'post_type' => 'about-me-items' );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :
    setup_postdata($post);
    // ...
endforeach;
```

But it shows all posts, nothing is skipped. I want to ignore latest one post. With this code now showing all latest three posts. This is running on `WordPress 3.8`.

Comment: Actually this code is right, I've getting problem with post entry mistake.

Answer (score 0):

replace this array with your $args.

```
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 3, 'offset' => 1,  'post_type' => 'about-me-items','order'=> 'DESC', 'orderby' => 'post_date' );
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need to use `global $post` here and your code should work. Since the `get_posts()` uses [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) so you may also give it a try, for example:

```
$args = array('posts_per_page' => 3,
       'offset' => 1,
       'post_type' => 'about-me-items',
       'orderby' => 'date',
       'order' => 'DESC'
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($query->have_posts()) :
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
        the_title();
        // more...
    endwhile;
endif;
```

But, your code should work (without `global $post`, it's not required). Check more on `Codex` about [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and [get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts).